# Catch the error from an async function in react application globally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I'm trying to add a global error handler so that I can catch all the errors and show some notifications to users.

```js
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", e => {
  console.log("unhandledrejection", e);
});

window.addEventListener("error", e => {
  console.log("error", e);
});
```

But this seems can't catch the errors from **async** functions:

```
function App() {
  async function asyncAction() {
    throw new Error("async error"); // This error can't be caught globally
  }
  function syncAction() {
    throw new Error("sync error");
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={asyncAction}>async</button>
      <button onClick={syncAction}>sync</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The code sandbox is here: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-sky-qxzzs?fontsize=14)

Comment: @JesperJohansson "Error boundaries do not catch errors inside event handlers." https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#how-about-event-handlers

Answer (score 0):

You have to await the result of the promise returned by the async function, because otherwise the error will not propagate to your global listener.

> It is however still possible for async functions to mistakenly swallow
>   errors. Take for example the parallel async function. If it didn't
>   await (or return) the result of the Promise.all([]) call, any Error
>   would not have been propagated. While the parallelPromise example seem
>   simple, it does not handle errors at all! Doing so would require a
>   similar return Promise.all([]).

[You can read more here in the MDN web docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

In your code sandbox I can catch the async error by rewriting the asyncAction function:

```
async function asyncAction() {

let p = new Promise(()=>{throw new Error("async error"); });

p.then().catch();
}
```